# QTP/UFT via ALM: window object not recognized

Tags: vbscript, qtp, alm

I have faced with situation which I have never seen before. 
My script creating Excel file, and during the saving some window appears on background, on which I should make some selection.

I have created snippet in UFT and which works from UFT. 
I have two versions, where my window object described as Window object and SwfWindow object. Both works. Activate, selection, button all works fine.

But when I injected this part of code to my framework and run it via ALM I always got "cannot identify object"

UFT 12.02

.Net plugin installed

I have no idea why this happens and how to fix this

Example of code

```
Window("text:=New Document").Activate
Window("text:=New Document").WinComboBox("swfname:=somename").Select "Option 1"
Window("text:=New Document").WinButton("text:=OK").Click
```

Comment: I suspect more information would be useful about how you inject "this part of code to {your} framework" ... Is your code using actual descriptive programming as in your example?  or, is that just scrubbed for public posting?  If you're actually using object names, I would suspect object repo scope could be an issue, but if you're actually using descriptive, then that shouldn't be the cause.  Perhaps you need an index or creation time property?

Comment: "Inject": just inserted my snippet to verification function (when window appears that listed actions should be performed). On framework used descriptive programming - it's correct. I'm wondering why this code work good from UFT, all windows and objects recognized, but when this part run as part of script started from ALM desired window not recognized. Already tried play with indexed but I have one test object, and which not recognized from the whole test set. From UFT I have tried different variants to describe my object, and all works fine

Comment: When running from ALM, is it still actually running on the same machine?  or is ALM running the code on a remote/VM machine instead?

Comment: All tests executed locally.

Comment: Do those new windows come from Excel application? Or some other apps?

Comment: Some other app (Titus plugin). This app regulates some privacy options while saving Excel file. So when I'm trying to save Excel this app appears and I should select some options